# Custom Firebase Email Verification Template and Action Handler

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-extensions

I would like to customize the email template (using the Trigger Email extension templates) to send verification links to users.

I understand it is not possible to change the template from the Firebase console as it prevents spam.

I am aware of the ability to customize action email handlers (The page that the user lands on when the link in verification email is clicked), as well as the ability to update the auth user's `emailVerified` property manually.

Is there also a way to generate the verification link that firebase would have used? One with the following properties:

- mode
- oobCode
- apiKey
- continueUrl
- lang

My ideal solution is to send a custom template to the user upon registration with the generated verification link. Direct users to a custom handler page, and use the `applyActionCode()` function as shown in [The Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page) to verify the email (I hope this implicitly updates the `emailVerified` property on the `Auth.User` record.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have achieved this by creating the user and generating the link on the backend with the admin SDK.

So your frontend would call a callable function or bespoke API endpoint for instance for the registration instead of using the SDK directly.

The callable would go about this:

- Creating the user in Auth: [auth.createUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user)
- Creating the user in your DB (Firestore, Mongo etc.)
- Assigning custom claims if required: `auth.setCustomUserClaims`
- Building the link for signin: [auth.generateSignInWithEmailLink()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in)
- Sending the email to an email transactional API

You will need an ESP e.g Sendgrid, MailChimp, MailGun etc. for the last step. There you will have all the freedom to build your own templates.

Please note that the `generateSignInWithEmailLink` will take care of verifying an email address and signing-in. It could therefore be used for login and registration.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you @Stf_F, 
Will this logic would work well for email and password auth, but will it also work for providers? I suppose I could write an Auth Function Trigger to do the latter part.

I also hope to customize the templates for password reset emails too (in the case of users signing in with email/password)- would I need to generate the auth link using FCF?

Lastly, Is there no way of generating action code links client side?

Comment: With social providers you don't need to send a verification email as they would have taken care of that already. As for password reset, yes, absolutely, same approach could be used:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link. Action code can be used on the client as well, but with the downside of less flexibility on your email template and design as this method will default to the stock emails. Check the sendSignInLinkToEmail() method for that.